# how to expand an image on click with JS?

Tags: javascript, css, image, gallery, expand

I created a gallery using the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/paula_m/pen/JjEmQZg) and now I'm trying to add the function click to expand an image, using this JS [method](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_modal_js). Sadly I cannot get it to work.

Any advice would be very helpful, either regarding this expand option or an alternative. Mind you I'm completely new to JS.

Thanks in advance!

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("image");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/*main div*/

.ponudba {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 3;
}

.image-grid {
  padding: 12px;
}

.image-row {
  display: flex;  
}

.image-row .image {
  margin: 12px;
  height: 220px;  
}

.image { 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  filter: contrast(75%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
              0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
              0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
              margin: 0 0 0 15%;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  z-index: 3;
}

.image:hover {
  filter: contrast(100%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-01 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg); 
  flex: 2;
  background-position: 50% 60%;  
}

.image-02 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg); 
  flex: 1.2;  
}

.image-03 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg); 
  flex: 1.5;
  background-position: 50% 70%;   
}

.image-04 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg); 
  flex: 3;
  background-position: 50% 60%;
}

.image-05 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg); 
  flex: 3;
}

.image-06 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg); 
  flex: 2;  
}

.image-07 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg); 
  flex: 1.5;
}

.image-08 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg);  
  flex: 2.5;
  background-position: 50% 70%;
}

.image-09 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg);  
  flex: 1;
}
.image-10 {
  background-image: url(images/...jpg);  
  flex: 3;
  background-position: 50% 80%;
}
#myImg {
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform: scale(0.1)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .image-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .image-row .image {
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="ponudba" id="ponudba">
    <div class="image-grid">
      <div class="image-row">
        <div class="image image-01" id="image-01"></div> 
        <div class="image image-02" id="image-02"></div>  
        <div class="image image-03" id="image-03"></div>  
        <div class="image image-04" id="image-04"></div>
        
      </div> 
      <div class="image-row">
        <div class="image image-06" id="image-06"></div>  
        <div class="image image-05" id="image-05"></div>
        <div class="image image-07" id="image-07"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-row">
        <div class="image image-08" id="image-08"></div> 
        <div class="image image-09" id="image-09"></div>
        <div class="image image-10" id="image-10"></div>  
      </div>
    </div>  
         <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="image">
         </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is your js code?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've edited my post. The code is just mashed together from the two sites, linked in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after asking a collegue for help, this is what I got - an image gallery with clickable images.

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/fullstackgenerator/pen/YzaqYdb

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal');

var imgaes = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("image-modal");
imgaes = [].slice.call(imgaes);

console.log(imgaes);

imgaes.forEach(function(item){
    item.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
      
  modalImg.src = this.getAttribute('src');
}
})

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

modalImg.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 }

.ponudba {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  z-index: 6;
}

.image-grid {
  padding: 12px;
}

.image-row {
  display: flex;  
}

.image-row .image {
  margin: 12px;
  height: 220px;  
}

.image { 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 95%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-01 {
  background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dtpgi0zck/image/upload/s--fMAvJ-9u--/c_fit,h_580,w_860/v1/EducationHub/photos/sun-blasts-a-m66-flare.jpg); 
  flex: 2;
  background-position: 50% 60%;  
}

.image-02 {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/KqzWwkCMPeZHFra2hkiJWj.jpg); 
  flex: 1.2;  
}

.image-03 {
  background-image: url(https://acs-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image//content/dam/cen/99/11/WEB/09911-feature3-venus.jpg/?$responsive$&wid=700&qlt=90,0&resMode=sharp2); 
  flex: 1.5;
  background-position: 50% 70%;   
}

.image-04 {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/yCPyoZDQBBcXikqxkeW2jJ-1200-80.jpg); 
  flex: 3;
  background-position: 50% 60%;
}

.image-05 {
  background-image: url(https://images.24ur.com/media/images/1000xX/Oct2020/51ae60002d9189cc75b0_62469955.jpg?v=6e93); 
  flex: 3;
}

.image-06 {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Jupiter%2C_image_taken_by_NASA%27s_Hubble_Space_Telescope%2C_June_2019_-_Edited.jpg/801px-Jupiter%2C_image_taken_by_NASA%27s_Hubble_Space_Telescope%2C_June_2019_-_Edited.jpg); 
  flex: 2;  
}

.image-07 {
  background-image: url(https://images.24ur.com/media/images/884xX/Oct2019/d33eec2c51_62323281.jpg?v=d41d); 
  flex: 1.5;
}

.image-08 {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Uranus_as_seen_by_NASA%27s_Voyager_2_%28remastered%29.png/800px-Uranus_as_seen_by_NASA%27s_Voyager_2_%28remastered%29.png);  
  flex: 2.5;
}

.image-09 {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Neptune_Full.jpg/640px-Neptune_Full.jpg);  
  flex: 1;
}
.image-10 {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Pluto_in_True_Color_-_High-Res.jpg/800px-Pluto_in_True_Color_-_High-Res.jpg);  
  flex: 3;
}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.modal-content {
margin: auto;
  display: block;
   animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform: scale(0.1)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .image-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .image-row .image {
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--a BIG thank you to @awecodeman!-->

<div class="ponudba" id="ponudba">
        <div class="image-grid">
          <div class="image-row">
            <div class="image image-01" id="image-01" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dtpgi0zck/image/upload/s--fMAvJ-9u--/c_fit,h_580,w_860/v1/EducationHub/photos/sun-blasts-a-m66-flare.jpg"></div> 
            <div class="image image-02" id="image-02" src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/KqzWwkCMPeZHFra2hkiJWj.jpg"></div>  
            <div class="image image-03" id="image-03" src="https://acs-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image//content/dam/cen/99/11/WEB/09911-feature3-venus.jpg/?$responsive$&wid=700&qlt=90,0&resMode=sharp2"></div>  
            <div class="image image-04" id="image-04" src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/yCPyoZDQBBcXikqxkeW2jJ-1200-80.jpg"></div>
          </div> 
          
          <div class="image-row">
            <div class="image image-05" id="image-05" src="https://images.24ur.com/media/images/1000xX/Oct2020/51ae60002d9189cc75b0_62469955.jpg?v=6e93"></div>  
            <div class="image image-06" id="image-06" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Jupiter%2C_image_taken_by_NASA%27s_Hubble_Space_Telescope%2C_June_2019_-_Edited.jpg/801px-Jupiter%2C_image_taken_by_NASA%27s_Hubble_Space_Telescope%2C_June_2019_-_Edited.jpg"></div>
            <div class="image image-07" id="image-07" src="https://images.24ur.com/media/images/884xX/Oct2019/d33eec2c51_62323281.jpg?v=d41d"></div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="image-row"">
            <div class="image image-08" id="image-08" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Uranus_as_seen_by_NASA%27s_Voyager_2_%28remastered%29.png/800px-Uranus_as_seen_by_NASA%27s_Voyager_2_%28remastered%29.png"></div> 
            <div class="image image-09" id="image-09" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Neptune_Full.jpg/640px-Neptune_Full.jpg"></div>
            <div class="image image-10" id="image-10" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Pluto_in_True_Color_-_High-Res.jpg/800px-Pluto_in_True_Color_-_High-Res.jpg"></div>     
                                                       <div id="Modal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content image" id="image-modal"></div>
          </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique.

If you have multiple images, you can use `getElementsByClassName` to get all elements you need to expand.

Then use for loop to add onClick function to each element.

```js
let imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("image"),
    imgModal = document.getElementById('image'),
    modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick = function (e) { imgZoom(e) }
}
function imgZoom(e) {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    let src = e.target.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/['"]/g, "")
    imgModal.src = src
}
let span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Because your image is `background-img` in css, use `backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/['"]/g, "")` to get url.

/*-----Edit-----*/

Sorry I made some mistakes in my code.

1. `let imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("image-row")` should be

   `let imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("image")`
2. `for (let i = 0; i < imgBlocks.length; i++)` should be

   `for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)`
3. `modal` is not defined
4. `background-img: url('...');` should write in html file, or js can't get the url.

   `<div class="image image-01" id="image-01" style="background-image: url('22.png');"></div>`

About your question

1. It's not necessary to add an id on every image (except modal) in this case.

   I select images by class name `image` in:

```
<div class="image image-01" id="image-01"></div>
```

3. Do I need to add a for loop for every element?

   You need to add `onclick` to every element you want to expand.

   Due to I selected images by class name, the object will be something like this

[image]

Use for loop to add `onclick` for every `<div class="image imag...</div>`

4. `style.backgroundImage` = `url('22.png')`
   `.slice(4, -1).replace(/['"]/g, "")` will create a string from `url("22.png")`, select `"22.png"`, then replace ' or " if exist.
   The final result will be `22.png`.

Comment: Guess I'm doing something wrong again because your code isn't working.

1) Updated the HTML in my question (changed the IDs from myImg to image-01 - and yes, 05 an 06 are intentionally that way)
2) yes, I have multiple images - ok got it
3) here's where things get blurry for me. I don't get the for loop. Do I need to add a for loop for every element?
4) I get the background-img, however I don't understand the part that comes after backgroundImage (.slice(4,-1)...). How do I create an url?

I somewhat understand but would appreciate a clarification on the whole matter as I'm mostly lost.